Why IIS return 502 error when rewrite URL to localhost?
i have a problen with Url Rewrite module 2 on IIS, i have configured the following rewrite :


I have two local services that are listening on port 51232 and 51233, these services do the same process but with different data.
When i access to my server with http://servername:8082/51232/service/process or http://servername:8082/51233/service/process, the URL is rewritten as http://127.0.0.1:51232/service/process or http://127.0.0.1:51233/service/process
I don´t have idea why is returning 502 error.
Since year ago it was working fine but today return a 502 error.
I have tried to restart the site, the server and it is not working, have you ever had some issue like this?
Thanks
